# memory leak warning on tomcat 7 shutdown

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks, warnings

I get the following message every time I shutdown tomcat.

SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferencesThreads The web application [/xxx] appears to have started a thread named [xxxxx] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Why is the message generated and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this message generated?

The web application [/xxx] appears to have started a thread named [xxxxx] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

> how can I resolve it?

You have successfully anonymized the thread name in your question. I can only assume that it's a thread that your webapp has started in the background (maybe not in your code, but in some library's code). Upon undeployment of your application, you'll have to shut it down, or stop using background threads altogether - e.g. through the use of executors.

Or, if you don't hot-deploy applications into the running tomcat, just ignore it: You'll only get this message upon shutdown of tomcat. If tomcat doesn't really shut down, you might need to make this thread a daemon, so that the JVM shuts it down when the main thread terminates. This is very pragmatic, but bad style.